# php:how to find result of variable from url string

Tags: php

I want to find variable from this url string:

this is my string :

```
$var = "http://localhost/trans/site/index#ads=10"
```

how can i get `$ads` from this string ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$var = "http://localhost/trans/site/index#ads=10";

echo $ads = parse_url($var, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
?>
```

outputs: ads=10

```
<?php

$var = "http://localhost/trans/site/index#ads=10";

$ads = parse_url($var, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);

echo $ten = (explode("=",$ads)[1]);

?>
```

outputs: 10